# QT installation of 5.1.1 MSCV2010 32bit over existing 5.6.1 MSCV2015 32bit version

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2015

I have been using QT 5.6.1 MSCV2015 32bit version for past month. It was working fine. But after I installed QT 5.1.1 MSCV2010 32bit version and Visual C++ 2010, QT 5.6.1 is not detecting the Visual C++ 2015 compiler.

The compiler which QT 5.6.1 was using is still present in list of auto detected compilers.

What might have caused this problem ? Any kind of suggestions are welcome.

NOTE : Qt 5.1.1 is detecting its visual c++ 2010 compiler.

Comment: Is any specific details are required to analyze the issue ?

Comment: "QT 5.6.1 is not detecting the Visual C++ 2015 compiler." Sorry, what? Are you talking about Qt Creator that you installed with the Qt 5.6.1 installer? Did you accidentally overwrite it?

Comment: yes, the QT creator that i installed with QT 5.6.1 is not detecting it. I installed both versions in different directory. But they share the same QtProject directory i guess.

Comment: I guess While installing I have overwritten some configurations, Better I will reinstall everything.